# toLowerCase method not working inside a filter method

Tags: javascript, javascript-controller

I am trying to use toLowerCase method inside a filter method. For some reason it doesn't seem to work. Not sure what I am doing wrong here. PLz advise!

```
mdu["aaUnits"] = allUnits.filter(x =>
 { return x.Name === distinctUnits[i] &&
  x.sumchans__status__c.toLowerCase() === 'on-billing'; }).length;
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? Do you get an error? No results? We'd need more code and/or error messages to help you.

Comment: It says unable to get tolowercase of undefined when I use the tolowercase method, without it the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Case-Sensitivity

Make sure that `sumchans__status__c` is in the correct case (e.g. that it is not `sumchans__Status__c` or some other alternative. If the code below does not work, check your field's name.

## Check Null First

If the value is undefined, you'll get an error. Check for that first. Example in the code below.

## Minor Optimizations

You can use the Arrow function more efficiently. When using just a single line, the arrow function automatically returns the value of the statement, so you don't need the `{ return` and `;}`.

---

```
mdu["aaUnits"] = allUnits.filter(
  x => x.Name === distinctUnits[i] && x.sumchans__status__c &&
  x.sumchans__status__c.toLowerCase() === 'on-billing').length;
```

Comment: Wow that worked awesome, just wondering why is it that you are using x.sumchans__status__c 2 times on the above code?

Comment: @Sumchans You'll want to read about [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). The second check (`x.sumchans__status__c`) is considered false if it is null, undefined, etc, and true otherwise. The && operator is a "shortcut operator", meaning the right-hand will only be evaluated if the left-hand is true; toString won't be called on a null value. If you don't like how that reads, you can also say `typeof x.sumchans__status__c === "string"`.